# how to make results shown in a bootstrap modal

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a form:

```
    <form method="post" action="save">
        <!--... some input field ...-->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

And the framework(I use CodeIgniter) maps the save requst to a function:

```
function saveAction()
{
    // some other logics
    $data['result'] = 'success';
    $this->load->view('result',$data);
}
```

and it jumps to the result page

```
<h1><?php echo $result ?></h1>
```

**The procedure above is very common, but I want to use twitter-bootstrap to show the result page in a modal. just like**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <h1><?php echo $result ?></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to do that? I think maybe some ajax callback is need.

About Bootstrap model:http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your modal first:

```
$("#myModal").modal({show:false});
```

Update the content with the new result and display the modal:

```
function saveAction()
{
    // some other logics
    $data['result'] = 'success';
    $("#myModal div:first").html('<h1>'+$data+'</h1>');
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
}
```

Comment: Your codes simply show a modal before submit the page, I want to a modal after the form submitted. I think the answer lies in this [page](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). I will thought it this evening.